# Pass query and function to another function

Tags: f#

I have a method which works fine:

```
 member this.GetItems = 
        let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()             
        let getQuery = 
            query {
                for row in db.ItemsTable do
                select row
            }
        getQuery 
        |> Seq.map (fun e -> new Item(e.ItemId, e.ItemName ))
        |> Seq.toArray
```

It make the select query to database, transforms each record to object and returns an array of such objects.

I want to split this method to two.  First one must be more general.  It gets query and function to transform record to object.

Here is my code:

```
member private this.ExecuteSelectQuery(query, transform_function) =
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()             
    query 
    |> Seq.map transform_function
    |> Seq.toArray

member this.GetItems = 
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()             

    this.ExecuteSelectQuery 
        query {
            for row in db.ItemsTable do
            select row
        } 
        (fun e -> new Item(e.ItemId, e.ItemName ))
```

But I get the errors:

- In this expression required type 'a * ('b -> 'c) but there is a type QueryBuilder
- This construction can be used only in the case of the method For

How can I fix it ?

**Updated:**

```
member private this.ExecuteSelectQuery query transform_function =
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()             
    query 
    |> Seq.map transform_function
    |> Seq.toArray

member this.GetItems = 
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()             

    this.ExecuteSelectQuery 
        query {
            for row in db.ItemsTable do
            select row
        } 
        (fun e -> new Item(e.ItemId, e.ItemName ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member function `ExecuteSelectQuery` expects the arguments as a tuple, so you have to use parentheses.

```
member private this.ExecuteSelectQuery(query, transform_function) =
    query 
    |> Seq.map transform_function
    |> Seq.toArray

member this.GetItems = 
    use db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()             

    this.ExecuteSelectQuery (
        query {
            for row in db.ItemsTable do
            select row
        }, 
        (fun e -> new Item(e.ItemId, e.ItemName )))
```

Please consider also the `use` keyword for binding of `DataContext` instance to correctly implement the disposable pattern. I've done it in my example.

Comment: Thanks.  It works, but I have one more question. I want to use the non-tuple version.  So I remove parentheses and comma, but have the error: This value is not a function and cannot be applied.  I have updated my question.  Is it possible ?

Comment: For the curried (non-tupled) version you need to put parentheses around `query {...}`. Without them, it gets parsed as two separate arguments to `ExecuteSelectQuery` instead of a single expression.